# Unusual effect of stroke-width for Circle

Tags: graphics

```
circle[lw_] := Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[lw], Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}]
GraphicsRow[circle /@ (10*Range[6])]
```

If I export this I get:

[image: five circles instead of 6]

This is also how it displays in a notebook.  Two things to notice: there are only 5 circles, and the line widths eventually get narrower instead of thicker.  I am looking for an explanation of these two behaviors.  (Separately, the export displays oddly in a notebook, but I am less concerned about that.)

Comment: It looks like where the black curve self-intersects, it turns white again.  This must be specific to your operating system or Mathematica version because it does not happen with M11 on OS X.  `AbsoluteThickness` sets the line thickness in screen pixels for 1.0x magnification, or in printer's points for printable formats like PDF or EPS.

Comment: @Szabolcs So you get a different result if you export to PNG?  I confirm that export to PDF gives the expected result EXCEPT that the 6th circle is still missing.  Do you see all 6?  (I'm using Mma 11 on Win10)

Comment: Works fine for me (version 10.0.4).

Comment: Reproduced with version 11.0.0 on Win7 x64.

Comment: What happens if you add the option `ImageSize -> 100` to your `Graphics`? I'm on Mac so I can't reproduce it. But similar things have happened before, hence my guess here.

Comment: @Jens That improves things: I see all six circles, and the PDF is probably correct.  Although the PNG now displays six circles (instead of just 5), the last one still has a "hole" in the center.  Furthermore, if I set `ImageSize->50`, I'm back to just 5 circles (and just 4 in the PNG), and the PDF displays bizarre artifacts.  Finally, we can see that now the EPS code simply does not contain the sixth circle, and we can see that oddly it uses `curveto` rather than `arc` for circle construction.  (Surely this will be the same on your OS?)

Comment: In MMA 10.4 under Linux Mint 17.3 I got six "circles", but the last two are a full octogon and a square O_o

Answer (score 6):

The problem is caused by `GraphicsRow` scaling the circles to fit a fixed overall image size while also maintaining the fixed thickness of the circumference line imposed on it by `AbsoluteThickness`. I think it is doing the best it can under the circumstances.

You can observe the struggle by giving the option `ImageSize -> Full` to `GraphicsRow` which allow it adjust the image size to fit the notebook window. Then when you drag your notebook window to be wider and narrower you will see how the circles change size but the circumference line stays at fixed size as specified.

```
GraphicsRow[
  Table[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[10 k], Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}], {k, 6}], 
  ImageSize -> Full]
```

In a narrow window

[image: narrow]

In a medium wide window

[image: medium]

In a very wide window

[image: wide]

These images are scaled by SE to look pretty much the same size in this post, but if you open them individually in new browser window or tab, you will see they actually have very different sizes and that, at the full image size, the circle circumferences maintain their specified thicknesses.

I am running V10.4.1 on OS X 10.10.2.